# Como sincronizar o git entre duas máquinas?

Tags: git

Tenho um projeto hospedado no `bitbucket`, acesso ele em minha máquina normalmente e atualizo os arquivo assim:

```
git add.
git commit -m 'novo nome'
git push
```

Os dados vão pra nuvem de boa.

Minha dúvida é: Quando eu tiver em outra máquina, como faço pra "puxar" os dados atualizados e continuar trabalhando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você precisa fazer um clone na sua máquina:

`git clone url` por exemplo:

vai até a pasta que você deseja despejar o projeto e rode o comando:

```
git clone https://github.com/juliohds/ProjetoIhelp.git
```

se precisar atualizar o projeto com os arquivos da nuvem use:

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 2):

Para clonar o repositório

```
git clone enderecoRepoOnline
```

Para atualizar

```
git pull
```